# How to blacklist of file:/// command in google chrome browser for Ubuntu 18

Tags: google-chrome, files

I wanted to blacklist the file:/// command on Chrome browser for ubuntu 18. Please
help . currently if i am  trying to open the file:///home in chrome browser it shows the output .

Regards
Nitin

Comment: This sounds like a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this? It's usually better to explain what you want to achive, not how you believe you should do it.

Comment: found the link which do the things in linux . not sure how to be done in ubuntu
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#URLBlacklist

Answer (score 2):

Create chrome URLBlacklist policy:

```
$ mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/{managed,recommended}
$ touch /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/URLBlacklist.json
$ chmod -R -w /etc/opt/chrome/policies
```

URLBlacklist.json policy:

```js
{
    "URLBlacklist": [ "file://*" ]
}
```

References:

- [administrators - Linux Quick
  Start](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start)
- [Block access to a list of URLs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=URLBlacklist)
- [URL blacklist filter format](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/url-blacklist-filter-format)

Comment: still file:///etc/passwd is working , no change after adding this policy

Comment: go to ```chrome://policy/``` see if it got applied without errors

Comment: Hi Bac0n please let me know if there is a way to load this jason policy for browser. Looks like its not taking the file which is updated in the /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/...

Comment: No it did not applied

Comment: keep in mind that chromium has a different policy path.

Comment: I am trying in Google chrome 80.0.3987.116

Comment: ```chrome://management/``` should say "Your browser is managed"

Comment: chrome://management/  says "Your browser is not managed by company or other organisation. Activity of this device may be managed outside the chrome.

Comment: To make it work browser should be managed ?